# Where angular holds DOM state, and based on what criteria

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Consider this scenario: You create a simple state multi-check, and you provide a search for it via angular filters. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OmidShariati/9gQTY/).

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Instant Search</h2>
  <div ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="filterText" />
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="state in states | filter:filterText">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="state.abbreviation">
            {{state.name}}
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Check **Alabama** and **Alaska**. Then re-filter the list to states that start with, say, **C**. Alabama and Alaska would be removed from the DOM. However, if you clear the filter, they appear again, but to my surprise, they appear checked. This means that angular should keep some kind of state, somewhere. But here I only have a simple string of states. No Ids, no keys, nothing. Just simple state titles. So, the question is:

1. How angular js holds or manages states?
2. How it does mapping (what kind of key or id is uses)?

Comment: what are the checkboxes for if you don't want to track their state? Could set up a directive to clear them whenever search is performed. Not clear what you need

Comment: I want to exactly know how angular js track them. see my second question (number 2).

Comment: as soon as you add `ng-model` a scope variable is created for 2 way binding, unless you have already created it. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel

Answer (score 3):

The state is saved in the model, there is no magic. When you said `ng-model=state.abbreviation` on selection it set `abbreviation=true`. The way to go about it would be to do something like

`<input type="checkbox" ng-model="state.selected">`

See my fiddle to understand how state is being tracked http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/XF6j6/ . When you check something see how the selected property changes.

If you don't want state to be tracked do not use `ng-model` on `input`.

Comment: I update that part of code as you say. I want to know How it does mapping (what kind of key or id is uses)?

Comment: Look at the input checkbox documentation. Everything is model driven, there is nothing like key or id. `ng-model` binds the selection value to property in the model. `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` can be used to assign custom value to model property.

Answer (score 2):

Angular has a concept of "scope" which is like a logical boundary for any given element (or any child of it). If you want to see how the scopes are defined in your example download and install this Chrome extension.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en

Basically a $scope object is a Javascript object which you use to add state and behaviour for your view or a portion of a view. Angular Framework takes care of the binding the state to the DOM. That is why it is a valuable framework :)

Any change to the state will instantaneously show up on the DOM. In your case, searching the list will internally add/remove items from the `states` list and the framework will draw the DOM from that filtered list. Now if some of the `state` items have been checked, those will remain like that in the list. Therefore when you remove the filter, those items are again processed by the framework and corresponding DOM elements are rendered along with the selected checkboxes.

When you use Angular you normally do not manipulate DOM elements directly, unless you are building up new interactive elements like Autocomplete or a dropdown menu etc. Therefor it is almost always unnecessary to have `id` on HTML elements (unless you have css using it).